# Codeigniter Pagination with GET next links not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, pagination

Hello guys what iam trying to accomplish here is to make pagination to my categories from $_GET method.

I got all rows, the category ID from the model and everything the posts are shown in the view page but when i click to see the second page i get the same results again from the first page. I am really close to that what i'm trying to accomplish but i cant fix this. Any help will be pleased.

```
public function sub_categories($start = 0){

  $data['category'] = $this->category_model->preview_categories(5,$start,$this->input->get('sub_id', TRUE));

  $config = array(
    'base_url' =>site_url().'/categories/sub_categories/?sub_id='.$this->input->get('sub_id', TRUE),
    'total_rows'=>$this->category_model->get_category_row($this->input->get('sub_id', TRUE)),
    'per_page'=> 5,
    'num_links' => 6,
    'page_query_string' => TRUE,
    'uri_segment' => 3,
  );

  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $data['p_links']=$this->pagination->create_links();
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my model for all cases

```
function preview_categories($num=20,$start=0,$sub_id ){

        $this->db->select();
        $this->db->from('posts');           
        $this->db->join('sub_categories', 'sub_categories.sub_id = posts.category_post_id', 'left');            
        $this->db->where('sub_categories.sub_id',$sub_id);  
        $this->db->limit($num,$start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

And this is what i have in URL when i click NEXT li

categories/sub_categories/?sub_id=2&per_page=5

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: why are you unsetting the config?

Comment: I was trying something else before that just left there, now i removed unset($config); sorry

Comment: Make sure your config for the following in config/config.php is set to true: $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; I don't recommend using these, though. Deviates from the codeigniter convention, and your URLs aren't as restful

Comment: Its true and the problem still exist.. Anyone ?

Comment: i think you're suppose to remove the `/` after `sub_categories` before your query string.

Comment: Also tried with this solution. Nothing changed.

Comment: are you sure you're sending the right parameters for the limit and the offset?!

Comment: Not so sure. How should i check this one ? How to send limit and offset parameters when using $_GET ?

Comment: Check the [tutorials](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) first. Then check the parameters for limit offset. Use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to check the last executed query.

Comment: You're doing it WRONG, You should take the offset from the GET variable not from a uri-segment so you'll have to remove the start argument from the function declaration & define it within the function as follows $start = $this->input->get('per_page')

Comment: Heey thanks Ahmad. That works like a charm. Really helpful. Finally i got this working.